# Given a controller function or route path, how do I get the full route URL in Express JS?

Tags: express, routes, express-router

I am writing an Express JS application and I need to calculate a route given a controller function or route path.

For example:

```js
let myUrl = functionToGetRoutePath(ThingsController.getThing); // would return https://host/api/v1/things/{id}

// Or

let myUrl = functionToGetRoutePath('/things/{id}'); // would return https://host/api/v1/things/{id}
```

Or, given parameters, it could fill in the URL parameters, for example:

```js
let myUrl = functionToGetRoutePath(ThingsController.getThing, { id: 1 }); // would return https://host/api/v1/things/1

// Or

let myUrl = functionToGetRoutePath('/things/{id}', { id: 1 }); // would return https://host/api/v1/things/1
```

Coming from .NET, this is pretty easy using UrlHelper:

`new UrlHelper(Request).Link("Things Route Name", new { id = 1 }); // returns https://host/api/v1/things/1`

Answer (score 0):

Does `req.originalUrl` help in this regard?

Comment: I suppose that if I'm rolling my own solution, that would give me a way to determine the base URL (host, root path, etc). But I'm hoping to leverage Express if I can.